# parameter that depends on the first one

Tags: typescript

I am writing a simple generic function which looks as follows:

```
function x<T>(a: T[], b: T) {
  return ''
}

x(['hello', 'world'], 'world')
```

I want the user to input an array of strings in the first argument, for example:

```
['red', 'yellow', 'green']
```

and I want the second parameter to be of type string, and it must be one of the values provided in the previous parameter, so the code editor should show auto complete the following options:

- red
- yellow
- green

if the user tried to write other than these, the code editor (or the compiler, I should say) should show an error.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try with `if (a.includes(b)) continue else throw your error`

Comment: @Vins, yes, of course. but I wanted to know if it's possible to show code auto-completion in typescript for this kind of scenario

Comment: If you want autocompletion you need to define the type you want to use inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the direction of inference by making a second generic parameter that extends the first.

```
function x<T extends string, U extends T>(a: T[], b: U) {
  return ''
}

x(['hello', 'world'], 'hello') // fine

x(['hello', 'world'], 'nope')
// Argument of type '"nope"' is not assignable to parameter of type
//   '"hello" | "world"'.(2345)
```

Note that `T` needs a constraint here like `T extends string`. Without it `T` is inferred as `string`, rather than any string literal type. Adding the `string` constraint seems to force the compiler to consider it could be a subtype of `string` instead.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwDwBVEFNlS2AEwGdEioAnGMAcwBpEBVbXfYxdAPgAoBDALnYBtALr0ARgIYBKRAG8AUIkTksUEOSQByTfIC+8+ci6DNACywAbC3E31NAdzjkLBTaMRnL1zTID0vxGAqLAMjE3MrGztHZ1d3TTA4AAcsH3l-RABBcmoQAFt8KEQ4YEQoAE8UjwAiRJTqzUQYEkSiniIiGGowHjELLDK4RCSech4CvHJi0oqqzWqI62rEAB9EapiXBoA6LgAmAGYAFgBWKQMgA)

---

You could also leave that constraint off and pass the array `as const` like:

```
function x<T, U extends T>(a: readonly T[], b: U) {
  return ''
}

x(['hello', 'world'] as const, 'hello') // fine

x(['hello', 'world'] as const, 'nope')
// Argument of type '"nope"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "world"'.(2345)
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ts=5.1.0-dev.20230310#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwDwBUA0iCqiCmyU+YAJgM6LoB8AFAIYBciATvvaQgDYCeVA2gF1sAI2Y4AlIgDeAKESt8UECyQByNbIC+s2clr81AC3xcucNdjUB3OCy6k1gxPUoQE5KFZNmLUgPT+iMAwYPi6+oY+5paINnYOTi5uHl5xYHAADvhqErKBiACCLADmIAC2JFCIcMCIUDzZcQBEGdnNaogwlBnVruQwJWD0Ilz49XCImfQs9JXELDV1DU1qzdFwzYgAPojNtvakHQB0tABMAMwALACsEkA)

---

Or if you are using Typescript 5.0 you const use [a `const` generic type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-rc/#const-type-parameters), to tell typescript to infer as const by default.

```
function x<const T, U extends T>(a: T[], b: U) {
  return ''
}

x(['hello', 'world'], 'hello') // fine

x(['hello', 'world'], 'nope')
// Argument of type '"nope"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "world"'.(2345)
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ts=5.1.0-dev.20230310#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwDwQQZyogKgGkQFVEBTZKUsAE0zwD4AKAQwC48BtAXUICN2iASkQBvAFCJEAJ1JQQUpAHJFYgL5ixyRh0UALUgBsDcRYUUB3OFIPVFPRHsPHFwgPSvEwGGFIatO-SMTM0trW3tFMDgAB1IXMXdEAEEpAHMQAFsqHDhgRCgAT1iHACIo2JLFRBg6KJxmTEwYVLBmXgNSfLhEaOYpZizKKURc-KLOxRLA4xLEAB9EEtCbSoA6RgAmAGYAFgBWQQ0gA)

---

All these options seem to play nice with autocomplete:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely not possible. Your function may receive different inputs at runtime, so it is impossible to know how the code is going to run at compile time (where TypeScript checks your types). For example, if I pass a randomly generated array, then how can the compiler know whether or not a value will be in a randomly generated array?

Rather than typing, it looks like you want to perform input validation, which checks the input at runtime. In your case, that's really easy:

```
function x<T>(a: T[], b: T) {
    if (!a.includes(b)) throw new Error('"b" is not in array "a"');
}

x(['hello', 'world'], 'world')
x(['hello', 'world'], '1')
```

Comment: typescript is really smart

Answer (score 1):

If the user is willing to append `as const` to the `a` value, the following works for me:

```
function x<T>(a: readonly T[], b: typeof a[number]) {}

x(['red', 'green', 'blue'] as const, 'green')
```

With that, my VSCode editor proposes the values of `a` for autocompletion of `b`. (Without the `readonly` and the `as const`, `T` is broadly inferred as `string`, as usual.)

But I observerd that I can still enter other `string` values for `b` without errors, so it seems the compiler does not enforce this, instead, it silently extends the `T` union type to accomodate any value given for `b`.

I am using VSCode, [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) and TypeScript 4.9.

Comment: Well the OP said: "if the user tried to write other than these, the code editor (or the compiler, I should say) should show an error." but in your solution, it does not https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ts=4.9.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwDwBUB8AKAhgLkQCcBTXAEwQBsBPRdAbQF0AaRAI0KhoAcS5giXAzAgAtuxJEmASkQBvAL4AoZcmwMA5KXKa2mgOakSYPYk3sqIEpqZCAzoggJ7UfUZInNMtRu0ldd2NTfUtrWwcnFzdzYBh7AAtvRAB6FMREuBAqckQpIjgiNkoSRzA4KCA

Comment: True; even worse, it will be obsolete with TypeScript 5